# How to get hash in mvc angular js 2 routing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular, routes, angular2-routing

https://localhost:444/Home#/test/test123

Main page will be Home , how to get Home# in all route i am using angular 2 and asp.net MVC

Comment: can you elaborate bit with url path code

Comment: @Ajay Thanks for the reply i have found one solution for that added <base href=""> in main page loading home page first and app.component.ts added this.route.navigate(['/test/test123']);